Merging paths in flow/alluvial/sankey diagram
My goal is to create a flow diagram where flows merge, basically a hierarchical flow like in this picture:

There are three levels (or points in time), marked in green. The difficulty seems to be that paths merge (i.e., two flows do not find together in a new flow that is twice as thick).
I've found no way to do this with plotly, Matplotlib's sankey, or pyalluvial. Maybe the trick is to stack figures on top of each other? But then how can I define where the flow terminates vertically at the farmost right green level? The figure should be symmetric (i.e., the flow should terminate in the vertical middle).
The cherry on top of a solution would be if I could influence where the flow terminates (e.g., at the points marked blue).
Edit
I've helped myself with a graph-based approach (which you can try yourself here by copying the code there).
g = gt.Graph(directed=False)
g.add_vertex(23)
g.add_edge_list([[0, 4], [1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7], [4, 8], [5, 8], [6, 9], [7, 9], [8, 10], [9, 11], [10, 12], [11, 13], [12, 14], [13, 14], [14, 15]])
pos = g.new_vp('vector<double>')
a = np.array([[-4.5, 3], [-4.5, 1], [-4.5, -1], [-4.5, -3], [-3, 3], [-3, 1], [-3, -1], [-3, -3], [-1.5, 1.5], [-1.5, -1.5], [0, 1.5], [0, -1.5], [1.5, 1.5], [1.5, -1.5], [3, 0], [4.5, 0], [-4.5, 3], [-4.5, 1], [-4.5, -1], [-4.5, -3], [0, 1.5], [0, -1.5], [4.5, 0]])
for v in range(23):
    pos[v] = a[v]
gt.graph_draw(
    g = g, 
    pos = pos, 
    #vertex_color = 'black', 
    vertex_fill_color = 'black', 
    vertex_size = 33, 
    vertex_pen_width = 0, 
    edge_pen_width = 33, 
    edge_color = 'black'
    output_size = (200, 200), 
    output = 'tree.png'
)


This works for me, still it would be nice to see if it can be done in Matplotlib etc.

Might require manually coding the shapes and their positions. Could you provide some sample data to help you get started?

Thanks, @amance, for your message. I've added a solution which uses coordinates.
